# How do I figure out which other JS files are interfering with one I am concerned about?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a page that has a `checkout from billing` function - that basically triggers some JS.

You can view [it here](http://apt-605.herokuapp.com/products/20).

Choose Blue & Small and add it to your cart.

Then go to checkout.

Enter some dummy data and press the 'copy from billing'. It won't work. But, if you refresh the page and do the process again...it will work.

Also, you will notice that in the first go around, the 'shipping method' dropdown doesn't work. But, once you refresh, it does.

I tried the JS responsible for this functionality in the console and it works fine, on the first load. So I know the code is right (all the fields it is trying to select are right, etc.).

How on earth do I debug this?

Comment: looks like no click event handler is attached to the element "copy from billing" the first time around. it just navigates to the top of the page as an anchor with a href="#" is supposed to do.

Comment: How do I fix that? And why would it not be attached the first time around, but be attached the 2nd time around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to verify the behavior on your site, and get it to work on the first load of the page, with one small tweak.  I think the order of loading is at the heart of the issue.

I was able to get it to work by rerunning the first line from your piggyback.js file after the page had loaded.

Here is a quick [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/1gKUH83nx1) showing the issue and quick fix.

If you could have this part run at the end of the load, I think that would fix it for you.

UPDATE 1:
You might also turn off turbolinks on the 'Proceed to Checkout' button.
When I added data-no-turbolink="true" to the link, then clicked, the page was not turboloaded, but loaded as a full page refresh. Then the copy shipping functionality worked as expected.

UPDATE 2: The real issue is most likely that your js code isn't triggering because it only expects a dom ready event. You might be able to trigger it when turbolinks loads it, using a page:load event, [as described here](http://srbiv.github.io/2013/04/06/rails-4-my-first-run-in-with-turbolinks.html).

Comment: Perfect. This does work. Your update is perfect. Thanks for the screencast too, nice touch! The only thing is the fix in the screencast wasn't what worked for me. Once I added the `data-no-turbolink` attribute around the `Proceed to Checkout` button it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what is happening...

On the cart page, `http://apt-605.herokuapp.com/checkout/cart` where you have the Proceed to Checkout Button, there is some javascript that is hooking onto all anchor tags, making an ajax request with the anchor tag's href and then replacing the content of the document with the content received from the ajax call.

What this is doing, is that the new content does not load like a new page, the head is never rendered, and the piggybak js is never loaded.

You can verify this, keep firebug open, switch to net tab, on the cart page. Now when you click on Proceed to checkout, you'll notice an XHR request is made to get `checkout`, and the checkout page loads without the net tab refreshing. You will also not see the puiggybak js loading in the net tab.

So basically you have to figure out what js you are using on your cart page that is attaching itself to all anchor tags, my guess would be a library that gives ajaxified navigation out of the box.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This sounds like `turbolinks` may be that library that is doing that. I disabled it around the divs that I wanted to, but I don't get why it is still not loading the `piggybak.js`.

Comment: So obviously the way you disabled turbolinks was incorrect! And my answer correct and should have been accepted dont you think?

Answer (score 0):

Are you ajaxing in the content?

You're head is missing

```
<script src="/assets/piggybak/piggybak-application-1d1707f6934602bfae8e3a33d27a4a9b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

javascript file on first load of page.

Comment: Hrmm....I am using a gem - https://github.com/piggybak/piggybak/ - but it should not be ajaxing at all. It should be loading this on the first page load. It's a simple copy call.

Comment: By the way, I just ran through it again and it does load this file the first time around. In other words, I have that file loaded in my `<head>` and it is still giving me the issue. Try testing it again in Incognito mode to see if you still see it missing on the first load.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Austin

The script 
`<script src="/assets/piggybak/piggybak-application-1d1707f6934602bfae8e3a33d27a4a9b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

is not getting called when you load the page at first, when you reload the page this link is inserted there dynamically, you must have written some code to handle that, If possible reveal that code so that we can help you further...